# change font color on scroll in navbar with jquery

Tags: jquery

Im creating a navbar so when i scrolls it's color background color changes it is working fine but when i scroll top navbar color cahnges to white but the font color remain white.

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 630 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 630) {

        document.getElementById("header").style.background = "#1c1a33";
        document.getElementById("header").style.transition = "500ms all";
    } 
    else{
        document.getElementById("header").style.background = "#fff";
        document.getElementById("header").style.color = "#333";
        document.getElementById("header").style.transition = "500ms all";
    }
```

}

as can be seen i have also define color when navbar scroll top but the background goes white font remain same as white color so how to change my font color?

```
document.getElementById("header").style.color = "#333";
```

Comment: just toggle a class... Hard to tell from that code why it would not work. My guess is there is an important at play

Answer (score 0):

you didn't set font color if `scrollTop > 630` you mean like this

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 630 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 630) {

    document.getElementById("header").style.background = "#1c1a33";
    document.getElementById("header").style.color = "#fff";
    document.getElementById("header").style.transition = "500ms all";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header").style.background = "#fff";
    document.getElementById("header").style.color = "#333";
    document.getElementById("header").style.transition = "500ms all";
  }

}
```

```css
body {height: 2000px;display: block}
#header {position: fixed; top: 0}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  header
</div>
```